# Multiple Ways Verifying Phone with Twilio's Authy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio, authy

I'm confused on how exactly to verify a phone with Authy.

I have a C#/MVC view that accepts a country code and phone number and I call AuthyClient.RegisterUser and that works fine. I store the AuthyId that comes back.

I then call AuthyClient.SendSms with force=true. <--- does this send them a verification code?

My test user didn't even enter a code on my site and in Twilio, he's showing as verified. Is that because he opened up the Authy app after getting registered?

Are there multiple ways to verify a phone then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The API requests you are making here, starting with the call to `AuthyClient.RegisterUser` is actually the way that you perform two factor authentication with the Authy APIs.

To verify a phone with Authy you only need to make two API calls. The first [sends a verification code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#request-a-verification-code) and the second requires the user to input the code they received and then [verifies it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#request-a-verification-code).

I can see you're using the [authy.net](https://github.com/authy/authy.net) library, which is sadly archived on GitHub now because it wasn't kept up to date. I'm not a .NET developer, but from what I can see in the codebase it didn't support the Verify endpoints. For this reason, I'd recommend you construct the HTTP requests yourself.

Take a read through the [Verify documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification), it has all the URLs you need to make requests to including the required parameters. Let me know how you get on with that.